# What is the block's 'justification' in substrate, what purpose does it serve?

Tags: substrate

In substrate, a block is often paired with a justification. Does this have to do with consensus mechanisms?

Comment: We had an update to our source docs as a result of this question which may be helpful: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/bbe90e31ed2fd71dc037fc385dae32584d2b1ce8

Answer (score 3):

A justification is a proof of finality of a block. For grandpa this is a commit + ancestry headers of all votes in the commit (so that we can verify the commit).

The terminology comes from the Tendermint implementation.

For example, in Tendermint it would be wrong to include all of the block signatures in the block hash, since you can have multiple valid sets of 2/3 pre-commits.

So you would rather fetch a *justification* of consensus on a block from your peers, then it doesn't matter which set of 2/3 pre-commits they send you.

Would be great if you had follow up questions that we could further clarify for you.